# how to assign server response to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to assign server response to an object, without success.

pls guide how to save this response to object?, have i defined user model correctly?

heres my user model

```
interface BelongsTo {
 class_id: string;
 section_id: string;
}
interface Userinfo {
 _id: string;
 name: string;
 user_id: string;
 roles: string[];
 belongs_to: BelongsTo;
}

export interface IUser {

 user: Userinfo
 token: string
}
```

and the response from server is

```
{
message: "Success"
user:{
    "_id": "60fbb4ec93eb4604658fc543",
    "name": "Irfan",
    "user_id": "irfan_123",
    "roles": [
        "student"
    ],
    "belongs_to": {
        "class_id": "60fbb3bb93eb4604658fc541",
        "section_id": "60fbb3eb93eb4604658fc542"
    },
    "created_at": "2021-07-24T06:36:28.006Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-07-24T06:36:28.006Z"
},
token: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIs.5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJCI6IkpXVCJCI6IkpXVCJ"
}
```

Comment: when i assign  this.user = user   , compiler throws eror -- Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'IUser | null'.ts(2322)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the name of the variable you have used as a server response? Is it something like `myResponse`? If so, you can access the property `user` inside that variable and finally store it in your desired variable `this.user`.

```js
this.user = myResponse.user; // myRespone is the variable you used to capture the server response and then you are accessing the user property.
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
let data = JSON.parse(response);
let userInfo = JSON.parse(data.user);
```